# Angular.js , PHP , JSON form not working

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, json

Edit: The form will trigger the php code and cause it to write null data to my JSON file. How do I make it so that my angular form sends the correct data to my php code?

I am very new to angular.js and I haven't worked in php for a while, but I am trying to build a very simple form in angular, and have it send data to a php file that then writes the information to a JSON file. The angular form is on a separate server from the php and JSON file. Below is what I have so far:

Index page:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" data-ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <title>AngularJS Form</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.25/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/modules/promise-tracker.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>
  <body class="container">

  <h2>AngularJs form</h2>

  <p>This is an AngularJs based form. It uses a controller to handle form validation and submission.</p>
  <p>Find a step by step tutorial on this form at <a href="https://www.lullabot.com/blog/article/processing-forms-angularjs">the Lullabot Blog</a>.</p>
  <a href="https://github.com/juampy72/angularjs_form"><img style="position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; border: 0;" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/github/ribbons/forkme_right_red_aa0000.png" alt="Fork me on GitHub"></a>

  <div data-ng-controller="help">
    <div id="messages" class="alert alert-success" data-ng-show="messages" data-ng-bind="messages"></div>
    <div data-ng-show="progress.active()" style="color: red; font-size: 50px;">Sending&hellip;</div>
    <form name="helpForm" novalidate role="form">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Your Name </label>
        <span class="label label-danger" data-ng-show="submitted && helpForm.name.$error.required">Required!</span>
        <input type="text" name="name" data-ng-model="name" class="form-control" required />
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="comments">Description</label>
        <span class="label label-danger" data-ng-show="submitted && helpForm.comments.$error.required">Required!</span>
        <textarea name="comments" data-ng-model="comments" class="form-control" required></textarea>
      </div>

      <button data-ng-disabled="progress.active()" data-ng-click="submit(helpForm)" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Angular Code:

```
/**
 * AngularJS module to process a form.
 */
angular.module('myApp', ['ajoslin.promise-tracker'])
  .controller('help', function ($scope, $http, $log, promiseTracker, $timeout) {
    $scope.subjectListOptions = {
      'bug': 'Report a Bug',
      'account': 'Account Problems',
      'mobile': 'Mobile',
      'user': 'Report a Malicious User',
      'other': 'Other'
    };

    // Inititate the promise tracker to track form submissions.
    $scope.progress = promiseTracker();

    // Form submit handler.
    $scope.submit = function(form) {
      // Trigger validation flag.
      $scope.submitted = true;

      // If form is invalid, return and let AngularJS show validation errors.
      if (form.$invalid) {
        return;
      }

      // Default values for the request.
      var config = {
        params : {
          'callback' : 'JSON_CALLBACK',
          'name' : $scope.name,
          'comments' : $scope.comments
        },
      };

      // Perform JSONP request.
      var $promise = $http.jsonp('process.php', config)
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          if (data.status == 'OK') {
            $scope.name = null;
            $scope.comments = null;
            $scope.messages = 'Your form has been sent!';
            $scope.submitted = false;
          } else {
            $scope.messages = 'Oops, we received your request, but there was an error processing it.';
            $log.error(data);
              console.log($scope.name);
          }
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          $scope.progress = data;
          $scope.messages = 'There was a network error. Try again later.';
          $log.error(data);
            console.log('name:', $scope.name);
        })
        .finally(function() {
          // Hide status messages after three seconds.
          $timeout(function() {
            $scope.messages = null;
          }, 3000);
        });

      // Track the request and show its progress to the user.
      $scope.progress.addPromise($promise);
    };
  });
```

Php Code:

```
<?php

   $myFile = "data.json";
   $arr_data = array(); // create empty array

  try
  {
       //Get form data
       $formdata = array(
          'name'=> $_POST['name'],
          'comments'=> $_POST['comments'],
       );

       //Get data from existing json file
       $jsondata = file_get_contents($myFile);

       // converts json data into array
       $arr_data = json_decode($jsondata, true);

       // Push user data to array
       array_push($arr_data,$formdata);

       //Convert updated array to JSON
       $jsondata = json_encode($arr_data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

       //write json data into data.json file
       if(file_put_contents($myFile, $jsondata)) {
            //echo 'Data successfully saved';
        }
       else 
            echo "error";

   }
   catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
   }

?>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What is your question? You've posted a bunch of code but have no indication of what problems you're facing, and we can't help at all if you don't say what's wrong. Consider taking the [tour] and checking the [help] for more information, especially the [ask] page and how to write a [mcve]. I look forward to helping if I can, but there isn't anything here to act on.

Comment: Oh sorry. I guess I don't really know how to phrase the question but My angular form is triggering my php code to run but the php code isn't writing the appropriate data tot he JSON file, and the Angular code is returning an error. I would like to know how to fix this issue?

Comment: What exactly is your title supposed to be saying? Angularjs is better than php, and php is better than json? or did you give them numerical values? is that some kind of conditional? or is it just nonsense.

Comment: It was suppose to show that I'm using angular to send a information to php that then writes the information to JSON.

Comment: @kyofanatic1 Well, what error is your Angular code returning? There are vastly different solutions if it's performing a `syntax error` vs a `timeout exception` vs an `out-of-memory error` (or a million others)

Comment: @Delioth It is saying:
undefined angular.js:10071
Type error: Cannot read property 'protocol' of undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in order to fix my issue I simplified my code. I left my php code the same but I ended up using a simple HTML form with a little bit of javascript in the page. My new code that works perfectly is found below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<form id="myForm" action="process.php" method="POST">
    Name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <br><br/>

    Message:<br>
    <input type="text" name="comments">
    <br><br>  

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 
    <script>
    $('#myForm').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var details = $('#myForm').serialize();
        $.post('process.php', details, function(data) {
            $('index').html(data);
        });
    });
    </script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `method="post"` to your form element.

```
<form name="helpForm" novalidate role="form">
```

to

```
<form name="helpForm" novalidate role="form" method="post">
```

HTML forms default to the GET method. You are trying to read POST variables in the PHP script.

```
   $formdata = array(
      'name'=> $_POST['name'],
      'comments'=> $_POST['comments'],
   );
```

Comment: I added that to my form but I'm still getting an error undifined  angular.js:10071, and the php is still writting null data to my JSON file.

Comment: Have you tried to `var_dump( $_POST );` to see what is being sent?

Comment: Where would I put that and how would I use it?

Comment: You can put it right at the top of your script and you should be able to see it in your developer tools in the Network tab.

Comment: What am i looking for in the network? I did get a new error though. It says uncaught syntaxerror: unexpected token { in my php file.